# Javascript library for fast rendering of thousands of DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dom, canvas

I have been recently playing with JavaScript and I am creating a web game (pure HTML + CSS + JS, no server backend). The main purpose of this game is walking with character over 2D map. (similar to https://alexnisnevich.github.io/untrusted/).

My current stack is:

- code written in TypeScript
- AngularJS for rendering
- and LESS + uglify for some minification

I created some basic functionality and now I increased map size from 10x10 (100 DOM elements) to 100x100 (10 000 DOM elements). And here is where Angular suffers. `ng-repeat` directive takes about 5 seconds to render this many elements (and 100x100 is small map for me, I want some bigger environment for user to move in)

Questions:

1. It seems I have chosen bad library for rendering. Angular is really slow when it comes to thousands of elements. Is there any faster library that can render more elements (and re-render those who have changed? it might be without checks, I have no problem firing render on changed elements manually)
2. Or have I chosen DOM elements as map wrong? Should I use canvas instead? The main reason why I used DOM elements is because I wanted all these events, every field on map is clickable and provides a tooltip when mouse is over that element. Is it possible to do so with canvas? What good library for creating 2D games for canvas is there (I never used canvas)?

Comment: This is off topic for Stack Overflow really (looking for library recommendations) - but I think you'll struggle to find _any_ library that can handle that many DOM elements efficiently as it will be the browser that's struggling, not the library.  It's simply not that quick to render many elements - older versions of IE were notorious for it.  It may simply be that you unfortunately need somewhat of a rethink of your rendering layer.

Comment: http://julian.com/research/velocity/

Comment: @JamesThorpe sorry for off-topic, I do not know all of SO-similar sites, any recomendations, where to put such a question?

Comment: @JoshHarrison the problem is not about animations, but about rendering many DOM elements. Animations could be in most cases handled by CSS anyway :)

Comment: Dom elements just have way too much junk for your use case. You might consider rendering the tiles yourself on a canvas and creating your own click events?

Comment: 1: If you don't show all the 10 000 elements at the same time, don't (try) to render them. Only render what the player can see (+maybe a small buffer) 2: you can do anything with canvas, but you have to do everything yourself

Comment: @dwana ad. 1: One element is actually size of one letter, like at link provided as an example, so on big screens, you can see at least 4/5 of elements, so it does not matter if you render 8 000 or 10 000 elements :) The problem is still there
ad. 2: I am currently looking for some good libraries / frameworks that work with canvas well :)

Comment: if 1 element == 1 char, it is indeed best to work an other solution. (native javascript / jquery works well with canvas^^)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have written over a dozen HTML5 games. To get the best result do not use a framework/library. Javascript is slow compared to native applications typically running at one tenth the speed. As games require a lot of repetitive rendering operations any extra overhead will negatively affect performance.

JavaScript and HTML5 already come with excellent built in API's for rendering, audio, video, user input (Keyboard, mouse, touch, and more), and resource management. Frameworks and libraries just add another level of abstraction, generally this abstract layer is designed to provide a wide set of functionality while most games, or specific parts of the game do not need or use most of this functionality. Every unneeded condition, function call, and memory allocation will negatively affect the performance.

That said there is still room for a Framework. But that should only be used for set up and browser compatibility. JQuery is designed for this (not for speed). Use JQuery to load and set up your page then for the game loop DO NOT use jquery. Use it only for non performance parts of the game.

For the best performance, your target is 60 frames per second.

- DO NOT use the DOM, or CSS. Create a canvas element and output
  everything to that. You will have to use it a little but every time you touch the DOM you kill 20+ game sprites/entities/tiles.
- Use the canvas 2D API or webGL (webGL is faster but has a more
  complex API) directly.
- Do not use SVG, or canvas 2D vector rendering calls (eg ctx.lineTo,
  ctx.arc) they are incredibly slow. If you need vector based graphics
  consider learning the webGL API
- use the HTML5 audio and video APIs directly. They are robust and very
  easy to use. You will spend the same amount of time learning how to
  use a framework as you do learning how to use the existing APIs
- Manage your memory usage. During the game loop you should not be
  incurring Garbage Collection (GC) at all. eg if you have a respawning
  entity it is tempting to just create a new object and dereference the old. Most frameworks do it this way. This will affect performance. DO NOT dereference during the game. Instead of deleting an entity and creating a new one, assign its properties with the new ones.

**Update 2018**
The following point still applies in part, but in the time between writing and this update there have been some improvements regarding ES6 features. Though still not all up to speed they are no longer the order of magnitude slower.

- ES6 has a great set of new features, class, forEach, let,
  destructuring, spread operators and more. DO NOT use any of these.
  They are so mind bogglingly inefficient that they are the kiss of
  death for your game. They are so bad that using polyfill (Javascript
  function to replace the built in function) is a whole order of
  magnitude faster (10 times +). Use `for` never `Array.forEach`,
  `Array.map`, etc. The for loop is up to 100 time faster than the
  built in iterators. 'let' for block scope seams like a good idea but
  no browser has optimized this. Using a variable declared with let is
  just as fast. It is the start of the block scope that requires the
  interpreter to assign memory, and where the scope ends it
  dereferences and incurs GC.
- Many people still believe in Object Oriented OO programing, many
  frameworks use OO as the foundation of their code. OO has its place
  and that place is large team written, multy revision corporate
  (enterprise) projects. OO is for programmers/code monkeys and has
  nothing to do with users/game players. Javascript has to be forced
  into conforming with OO paradigms and in doing so you introduce
  overhead, overhead that will negatively impact your game. Javascript
  is designed for "add hoc" structuring and it is very good at it.
  Learn to use closure and don't get caught up in the OO paradigms if
  you want to write fast games.

So now I have turned you away from frameworks you look at your IDE and wonder where do I start. 
Start here
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and learn how to use the existing API's rather than some framework, it will require the same amount of effort to learn but in the end you will be coding closer to the hardware and producing faster games.

What about physics, complex hierarchical animation, multiplayer state management and communication. Github is a great place to start, small targeted APIs are the best. Don't just download a git and add it to your game. Download and rip it apart, remove anything you don't want, take only what you need, rewrite it to fit your needs and only your needs.

So you still want a framework? Well I don't blame you, I have 40 years of writing games under my belt and it's easy to say do it all yourself.

I recommend [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) I have looked very closely under its hood and though not entirely optimised, it has good community support, is well written and easy to understand and provide the closest to hardware solution I have seen for a game framework.

One last thing. Do not write a game that will run on every device under the sun, a game for phones will never work well on a PC and the other way around. Responsive design is for web "pages" not a thing for high performance games, unless you have years of experience coding, or you are just having some fun to fill in time between your day job.

And remember Programmers write games, game designers dream.

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for all opinions. I will completely rethink architecture and I will see if this will go somewhere.

Comment: Brilliant insights. @Blindman67 Have you ever used DOM elements with libraries like Tailwind? I wonder if applying Tailwind classes to several thousand elements individually, is slower than writing my own classes & cascading.

Comment: Lots of good insight, but to clarify one thing: _"Javascript is slow compared to native applications typically running at one tenth the speed"_ -- this is not _that_ true anymore. There are various benchmarks out there for equally optimized code, such as [this one](https://benchmarksgame-team.pages.debian.net/benchmarksgame/fastest/node-gpp.html), but in general, JS is not magnitudes slower than equally optimized C++. The DOM, on the other hand, is another story, that's still awful slow in many cases, even with extensive optimization.

Comment: @JohnWeisz On fixed sized data structures and basic number crunching JS is a good competitor, but this is a very limited set of applications. JS lacks many basic optimisations  that give native languages that order of magnitude advantage (fast floats, tail calls, better memory management, SIMD, to name a few) . Object manipulation in JS kills it's performance well before getting near the DOM, and doing anything without organised data structures (`Object` in JS, `struct` in C/C++, `class` in C++) is a lot of effort that is better spent writing native.